# Java jpackage not working correctly on MacOS Big Sur

Tags: java, macos, macos-big-sur, jpackage

I'm using jpackage to build a Mac dmg installer for my application.

On Mojave, the generated dmg looks great, it has a nice icon and background image showing the user they need to drag the app to the Applications folder:
[image]

On Big Sur, the background image is gone and the application icon looks like a folder:
[image]

Bad UX.  I'm using the same jdk (jdk-16.0.2.jdk) and switches on both OSes.

Anyone else run into this issue?

Comment: Have you resolved the issue meanwhile? How exactly are you running jpackage? Have you considered overriding builtin resources? https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/jpackage/override-jpackage-resources.html#GUID-1B718F8B-B68D-4D46-B1DB-003D7729AAB6